# css ellipsis not working

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I used below css for ellipsis but dots are not coming can anybody tell me is there anything wrong in my css.

Thanks in Advance

```
.inbox-message-list li .message-suject{
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    display:block; 
}
```

Comment: Text-overflow doesn't work vertically, can that be your problem?

Comment: there is no wrong in your code. i think classes calling is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, try it in this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ox7h59h9/)

The problem is you had a typo `.message-suject` and in your html apperently is `.message-subject` with a `b` like it is supposed to be

Answer (score 0):

Please try this... 
You need to mention fixed width for the text container, so that if the text exceeds that width then ... will apear:

HTML:

```
<ul class="inbox-message-list">
<li class="message-suject">
  This is some long text that will not fit in the box

</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.inbox-message-list li.message-suject
{
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width:150px; 
  overflow:hidden !important; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important; 
  display:block;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/satyaprasanna/p89hwed3/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Change CSS :

```
.inbox-message-list li.message-suject
{
 white-space: nowrap; 
 width:150px; 
 overflow:hidden !important; 
 text-overflow: ellipsis !important; 
 display:block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is like this then CSS rules is working

```
<ul class="inbox-message-list">
  <li>
    <div class="message-suject">
sdjkfhjksd fsjkfhskdhf ksdhfksdj fksdahfsdka fhsdkajf sdakfhksd afhsdk fksdhfksd fgsdk fksdhfksdhfkjshdf kshdfksd fkshad fksdhfkshdfkhsadkfhskdhfdsfsd
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z1aey05k/